# How to catch exception when attempting to delete a file in use?

Tags: vb.net

I't making a program to delete the files in my temp folder. I've gotten as far as the code to delete the files, But I can't seem to figure out how to skip the files in use or catch the exception so that my program doesn't crash when it attempts to delete a file in use.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            Dim s As String
            For Each s In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\" + System.Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Local\Temp")
                System.IO.File.Delete(s)
            Next s
        End If
end sub
```

Comment: [`Path.GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend. It's not 100% guaranteed that the user's profile directory has exactly the same form as their user name, nor is it guaranteed that `C:\Users` is the correct root path to the profiles directory.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Try/Catch block to catch errors (exceptions)

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        Dim s As String
        For Each s In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\" + System.Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Local\Temp")
            Try
                System.IO.File.Delete(s)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("File could not be deleted : {0}", ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next s
    End If
end sub
```

That will allow your program to ignore the error and continue processing the next items.

Comment: No love for `On Error Resume Next`? :^)

Comment: That worked lovely, I was attempting to do that same thing, but I had try after "Next s" and that is Probably why, Thanks a bunch

Comment: No love at all, that thing should have never existed :)

Comment: I am not going to put a downvote, but catching a **generic** exception is very bad idea, when [something like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception(v=vs.110).aspx) exists.

Answer (score 1):

When an exception is thrown, once it is handled by the `Catch`, execution will jump to the `End Try`.  Therefore, *where* you place the beginning and ending of your `Try`/`Catch` block is important.  For instance:

```
Try
    Dim s As String
    For Each s In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\" + System.Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Local\Temp")
        System.IO.File.Delete(s)
    Next s
Catch ex As IOException
End Try
```

In the above example, if any call to `Delete` fails, it will jump to the `End Try` and skip the rest of the iterations of the `For` loop (thereby skipping the rest of the files).  However, consider this:

```
Dim s As String
For Each s In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\" + System.Environment.UserName + "\AppData\Local\Temp")
    Try
        System.IO.File.Delete(s)
    Catch ex As IOException
    End Try
Next s
```

In this second example, it will jump to the `End Try` and then continue to the next iteration of the `For` loop (thereby continuing on the the next file in the list).

Also, as noted in the comments, above, you definitely ought to be using `Path.GetTempPath` to get the path to the temporary folder.  You should not construct the path yourself, since it could change.  For instance, Windows does not require that you user folder has to be under `C:\Users`.  You can actually change that.

Comment: Bad practice of eating exceptions like this.

Comment: @Neolisk Yes, it is.  I was just trying to keep the example simple, but you're right, I shouldn't even hint that something like that is good practice.  I updated my answer.  Thanks again!